# Can we run Visual Studio Test Agent in interactive mode when logged in with different account

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I configured my VM to run a test agent in interactive mode with a account A. If I login to the VM with account A, all works fine as expected. But If I try to login with my account the test agent doesn't run using account A.

My question is: Can I login to this VM with my own account and launch the test agent using account A?

It need to run in interactive mode. So far when I do this I get a pop-up after the login saying that test agent cannot run in interactive mode since it's been configured with another account.

I configured the test agent using MTM and also tried directly through the test agent configuration tool. I'm using VS 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the account you're logging in with on the machine must be the same as the account configured for the test agent. See the following link:

[How to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests that Interact with the Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx)

***"If you are running coded UI tests that start a browser, the service account for the test agent is used to start that browser. This service account must be the same as the user account that is the active user on this computer. If it is not the same user account, the browser will not start."***

Another good resource for setting up tests agents when working with different network topologies

[Setting Up Test Controllers and Test Agents to Manage Tests with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546459.aspx)

You can take a another route and set up a lab service account:

[Using a Lab Service account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546460.aspx)

***"The lab service account allows test agents to connect to a test controller with a single user account, so you can avoid manually setting up user accounts on multiple machines. If the lab service account is already configured on the test controller, then when you create a lab environment, Microsoft Test Manager automatically retrieves the credentials of the account and uses them to configure the test agents. The lab service account also ensures that your test agents run and communicate with your test controllers using minimal permissions. "***

Hope this helps!